# When building a UE 4.27 project in Visual Studio 2022, it throws an error with code 3

Tags: c++

I am a beginner and when building code in Visual Studio 2022 I get an error with code 3

Ошибка  MSB3073 выход из команды "C:\UE_4.27\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat MyProjectEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:\UE_4.27\Progect\MyProject\MyProject.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" с кодом 3. MyProject   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets    44

WHAT WAS I TRYING TO DO:

1. Reinstall Visual Studio 2022
2. Reinstall Unreal Engine 4.27
3. Install old versions of Visual Studio
4. Update everything to the latest version

(Nothing helped)

This Character class code looks like this

```
CPP:                                                                                                  

#include "tozhemoy.h"                                                       
#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"
#include "Components/CapsuleComponent.h"
#include "Components/InputComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/CharacterMovementComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/controller.h"
#include "GameFramework/SpringArmComponent.h"



bDead = false;






h:
UPROPERTY(EditAnyWhere, BlueprintReadWrite);
bool bDead;
```

I entered other lines of code, but they did not affect anything (these lines were supposed to affect movement). And with them, too, the same error came out.
Please help, because of this error, none of the code in Unreal Engine does not work.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Seems like one cause could be [a misspelled path name](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f70c2425-14de-49cf-b228-d29548c9ef87/getting-error-msb3073?forum=msbuild). Makes me wonder if `Progect` really is a part of the project path. (Just guessing)